# How can I edit a typo?

Tags: discussion, editing

Today I found an [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/160950/139191) that has a typo (misspelled gastly), wanted to edit it but couldn't because of minimum character amount. What to do in cases like this one?

Comment: I edited it for ya, so it's done now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few things you can do when minor edits need to be done:

- Leave a comment on it alerting the op of his minor mistake.
- Look through the post to see if anything else can be edited as well, such as other spelling errors or any grammar errors.
- If the op hasn't fixed it, or there aren't any other things to edit, you can visit [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) and let someone know. Users with 2k+ rep often are in chat and can edit it for you, as they are not limited by minimum amount of characters changed to edit something.

Comment: Why does this limit exist for low rep users? I can imagine the answer is obvious but it begs asking nonetheless. :)

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I'd assume it's at least partially because there is a rep gain (albeit small, but it exists) for <2k users to make edits, so the changed character count is an attempt to make sure the edit is meaningful (no abusing the edit system, clogging up the suggested edit queue). >2k users making edits don't get the rep bonus, so I guess it's seen as more of a "betterment of the site and the content on it" when they make an edit, so even the tiniest edits can fulfill that. I'm **sure** there's a meta somewhere that explains this better than I can... :)

Comment: It definitely helps, thank you! It does make sense when you put it that way, I also didn't know that users above 2K rep didn't receive any from edits.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf, it is sort of a trade off. Below 2k rep, you have more limitations but a greater reward. Above 2k, you have less limitations and less rewards.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf because it means that two people have to review the change, it's a waste of time for trivial changes such as one character. Also it encourages the low rep user to review the rest of the post and find and fix/improve other problems with it instead of just one problem.

Comment: Alternatively just leave a comment and somebody with instant edit privilege will come by, see it and make that edit for you (if the poster doesn't see it before that).